# ERROR: delete on table "....." violates foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

So I'm using JPA and I have a ManyToMany relationship between tasks and employees (each employee may work on many tasks at once, and each task can be assigned to multiple employees)

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Task {
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    @Transient
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_task",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"))
    private List<AppUser> employees;
}
```

and this is the employee (appuser) entity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="employee")
public class AppUser {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String first_name;
 @Transient
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "employee_task",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id"))
    List<Task> tasks;
}
```

this is what my employee_task table looks like :

```
task_id employee_id
    2      11
    3      12
    5      14
    6      15
    7      16
    8      14
    9      17
    11     14
    13     19
    14     20
    15     21
    16     22
    17     23
    1      8
    69     8
    4      8
    70     8
```

when i try to delete a task, i get this error  :

I'm trying to delete the parent student or parent course and I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "task" violates foreign key constraint "fkqarvh9t68lancucpltm11ch5p" on table "employee_task"
```

Comment: What is your question? The error is pretty clear, you can't be assigned to a task that doesn't exist

Comment: @HoneyBadger i'm trying to find a way to be able to delete a task without getting this error ( idk where you got the 'doesnt exist' part from ).

When I try to delete task 4 , i get this error (despite the task clearly existing)

Comment: point is, you try to remove a task while somebody is still assigned to it. Removing the task would mean somebody was assigned to a task that didn't exist (anymore). Since that isn't allowed, the delete cannot be performed. You can only remove a task nobody is assigned to.

Comment: so what solution do you propose? i should unassign manually before deleting? I thought JPA already took care of that and I don't need to do it manually